# Chain Commands in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to copy and paste a folder structure on file system programmatically. I did it with help of recursion successfully. But for certain validations I need to implement chain of commands (which i observed in eclipse java).

Does the chain of commands exist in C#.Net?

I looking for an example on chain of commands.

Comment: Posting an example of what you are after would help.

Comment: 'Chain of commands' sounds too vague, can you give an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chain of Command is a design pattern. It is well documented, and has been successfully used in many software solutions. An article on [Chain of command in .Net](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/39166/Using-the-Chain-Of-Command-Design-Pattern-Concepts)

In brief, this pattern involves a sequence of `loosely coupled programming units`, or `handler objects`. These objects are coupled together to form the links in a c`hain of handlers`.

Each handler performs its processing logic, then potentially passes the processing request onto the next link (i.e. handler) in the chain. A client using the chain will only make one request for processing.  After this request, the chain handlers work to do the processing.

Comment: Ah, looks like I completely misunderstood the question! */me deletes answer*